# How do I know the resistance of a logic level MOSFET transistor?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, driver

I have recently gotten into the microcontroller scene, and I have been stumped with a question all day. My microcontroller's GPIO pins cannot handle more than 20ma; I want to connect a MOSFET transistor https://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_783455_-1
to my microcontroller, so I can control a larger circuit. How can I tell how much resistance the transistor adds to the circuit? I feel like I need to know this so I can use V=IR to calculate the resistor I need to make the circuit safe for the microcontroller.

Comment: The linked part is a PNP bipolar junction transistor (BJT), not a MOSFET. It's also a bit clear which resistance you are looking to calculate. A transistor, being a three terminal device, has potentially three ways current can flow through it. A schematic would help.

Answer (score 6):

If your MCU is driving the base of a BJT transistor, a safe value of a resistor is 5K-10K. This limits any in/ out current to below 1 mA and still drives the BJT into saturation easily.

In the case of a MOSFET, even if there is no gate current but gate charge, the same value helps limiting current peaks when switching.

Comment: @MichaelKaras good use of words.